# Pandas Timeseries Broadcasting Future Warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am getting a future warning:

> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:2850:
>   FutureWarning: TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by
>   default is deprecated. Please use DataFrame. to explicitly
>   broadcast arithmetic operations along the index   FutureWarning)

When using Pandas for operations like these:

```
Lg = rho_a*cp_a/(gamma*(ra+rsub))*(es_g-ea)/ lv_a * 3600
```

Where each name is of type Series. What would be the equivalent expression? I mean am I honestly going to have to write something like this in the future?

```
Lg = rho_a.multiply(cp_a).divide(gamma.multiply(ra.add(rsub))).multiply(es_g.subtract(es).divide(lv_a) * 3600
```

That's just plain ugly. I like  being able to do the former operation because all of the timestamps are nicely lined up for when the data is not so nice.

Is this really what this warning means? 
Is there a better way to do this type of operation with pandas?

Comment: You say that "each name is of type Series"; are you sure one of them isn't a DataFrame, and not a Series?

Comment: I think actually one of them was a DataFrame when I posted. I made a small change after the fact and wasn't getting the warning anymore because one of the variables was now a Series as opposed to a DataFrame. What a relief that is.